# How to pass farebasis code in EnhancedAirBookRQ?

Tags: java

In case of `branded` fares for each flight we can get multiple faretypes (different farebasis codes), How can we perform the `EnhancedAirBook` on a higher `faretype` ?

By default we are getting the cheapest faretype details in response, so What will be the sample request for `EnhancedAirBook` to get the selected `faretype`

This is the below request which I have tried, for which I have received only one faretype which is of cheapest fare, so how pass in the request with selected `faretype` (farebasis code)

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ
            xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_10" version="3.10.0" HaltOnError="true">
            <OTA_AirBookRQ>
                <HaltOnStatus Code="NN"/>
                <HaltOnStatus Code="UC"/>
                <HaltOnStatus Code="LL"/>
                <HaltOnStatus Code="PN"/>
                <HaltOnStatus Code="NO"/>
                <HaltOnStatus Code="US"/>
                <HaltOnStatus Code="UU"/>
                <OriginDestinationInformation>
                    <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2023-09-15T15:05:00" FlightNumber="1666" ResBookDesigCode="P" NumberInParty="1" Status="NN">
                        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="IST"/>
                        <MarketingAirline Code="TK" FlightNumber="1666"/>
                        <MarriageGrp>O</MarriageGrp>
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="HAM"/>
                    </FlightSegment>
                    <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2023-10-17T06:55:00" FlightNumber="1661" ResBookDesigCode="P" NumberInParty="1" Status="NN">
                        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="HAM"/>
                        <MarketingAirline Code="TK" FlightNumber="1661"/>
                        <MarriageGrp>O</MarriageGrp>
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="IST"/>
                    </FlightSegment>
                </OriginDestinationInformation>
                <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="5" WaitInterval="1000"/>
            </OTA_AirBookRQ>
            <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
                <PriceRequestInformation  Retain="true">
                    <OptionalQualifiers>
                        <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="EUR">
                            <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                        </PricingQualifiers>
                    </OptionalQualifiers>
                </PriceRequestInformation>
            </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
            <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
                <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="5000" UnmaskCreditCard="false"/>
            </PostProcessing>
        </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.